# Incorrect sys.path when executing orgmode python code block under venv

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode, python-venv

When executing python code block with `session` modifier python uses global modules but not local, althrough `venv` is activated. But while executing the same code block without `session` modifier uses local modules as expected.

The steps to reproduce the issue:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ pyenv local 3.10.6
$ python -m venv .venv
$ . .venv/bin/activate
$ pip install numpy scipy
$ emacs test.org
```

Where `test.org` is:

```py
#+begin_src python :results output
try:
  import numpy
  print('numpy imported')
except ModuleNotFoundError as err:
  print(f'ERROR: {err}')
try:
  import scipy
  print('scipy imported')
except ModuleNotFoundError as err:
  print(f'ERROR: {err}')
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.path)
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :session :results output
try:
  import numpy
  print('numpy imported')
except ModuleNotFoundError as err:
  print(f'ERROR: {err}')
try:
  import scipy
  print('scipy imported')
except ModuleNotFoundError as err:
  print(f'ERROR: {err}')
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.path)
#+end_src
```

After executing `org-babel-execute-buffer`, the results for the first code block should be:

```
#+RESULTS:
: numpy imported
: scipy imported
: /home/sd/projects/test/.venv/bin/python
: ['', '/home/sd/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python310.zip', '/home/sd/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10', '/home/sd/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/sd/projects/test/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

Here `sys.path` contains `site-packages` from `.venv`, so only local packages are being used.

For the second code block (with session), the results should be:

```
#+RESULTS:
: numpy imported
: ERROR: No module named 'scipy'
: /home/sd/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/python
: ['', '/home/sd/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python310.zip', '/home/sd/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10', '/home/sd/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/sd/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/home/sd/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

Here, `numpy` was imported but `scipy` was not found because `sys.path` contains `site-packages` from `.local` and `.pyenv` directories, but not from `.venv`, so Python uses only global packages, but no local ones.

In the first case (without session), `sys.executable` equals `: /home/sd/projects/test/.venv/bin/python`, which is correct. In the second case (with session), `sys.executable` shows `/home/sd/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/python`, so Python does not recognize that it is under a virtual environment.

How can this issue be fixed without manually setting `sys.path`? In both cases, the executable should be the same for both the simple code block and the code block with session.

Comment: You might want to try posting this in https://emacs.stackexchange.com to get some more visibility.